# How to finish this Google Calendar Api v3 - FreeBusy PHP - example?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I want to use the google api v3 freebusy (php) to find free freebusy-information of three of my calendars, but I dont find the correct ending to my code. I want to access the "calendars - busy" values of the $freebusy-response.

Since there is no example-code at the api-reference and i couldnt find any working code on the web (but lots of people asking for it) you guys are my last hope to get this running.

```
...
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client); // successfully connected
$freebusy = new Google_FreeBusyRequest();
$freebusy->setTimeMin('2013-07-08T08:00:00.000-07:00');
$freebusy->setTimeMax('2013-07-08T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$freebusy->setTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$freebusy->setGroupExpansionMax(10);
$freebusy->setCalendarExpansionMax(10);
$mycalendars= array("my_calendar_id1@developer.gserviceaccount.com","my_calendar_id2@group.calendar.google.com","my_calendar_id3@group.calendar.google.com");
$freebusy->setItems = $mycalendars;
$createdReq = $service->freebusy->query($freebusy);

echo $createdReq->getKind(); // works
echo $createdReq->getTimeMin(); // works
echo $createdReq->getTimeMax(); // works
$s = $createdReq->getCalendars($diekalender);  
Print_r($s, true); // doesn't show anything
    // needed: the value of "calendars": { (key): { "busy" - array of one or all calendars
```

This is what the API-reference says about the response:

```
  {
    "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
    "timeMin": datetime,
    "timeMax": datetime,
    "groups": {
        (key): {
        "errors": [
            {
            "domain": string,
            "reason": string
            }
        ],
        "calendars": [
            string
        ]
        }
    },
    "calendars": {
        (key): {
        "errors": [
            {
            "domain": string,
            "reason": string
            }
        ],
        "busy": [
            {
            "start": datetime,
            "end": datetime
            }
        ]
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my resolution (only the setItems part of your code is wrong):

```
$freebusy_req = new Google_FreeBusyRequest();
$freebusy_req->setTimeMin(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime($date_from)));
$freebusy_req->setTimeMax(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime($date_to)));
$freebusy_req->setTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$item = new Google_FreeBusyRequestItem();
$item->setId('{calendarId}');
$freebusy_req->setItems(array($item));
$query = $service->freebusy->query($freebusy_req);
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
$service = new Google_CalendarService($client); // successfully connected
$freebusy = new Google_FreeBusyRequest();
$freebusy->setTimeMin('2013-07-08T08:00:00.000-07:00');
$freebusy->setTimeMax('2013-07-08T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$freebusy->setTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$freebusy->setGroupExpansionMax(10);
$freebusy->setCalendarExpansionMax(10);
$mycalendars = array( array("id"=>"my_calendar_id1@developer.gserviceaccount.com"), array("id"=>"my_calendar_id2@group.calendar.google.com"), array("id"=>"my_calendar_id3@group.calendar.google.com"));
$freebusy->setItems($mycalendars);
$createdReq = $service->freebusy->query($freebusy);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am working in Grails and this works for me.

```
def heute = new DateTime(false, new Date().time, null)
def heutePlusEinJahr = new DateTime(false, (new Date() + 365).time, null)

println heute
println heutePlusEinJahr
Events feed = servicecalendar.events().list(calendarId).setTimeMin(heute).setTimeMax(heutePlusEinJahr).execute();
return feed
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Write it here so people can see it and copy it if needed. Additionally, explain how your answer solves the problem (by editing your answer and adding more detail)